# Why does it always return original value?

Tags: java, android, syntax, casting

I have the following function

```
private Integer calculateWeeklyValue(String p_Value, String Frequency) {

    if (p_Value.length() == 0)
        p_Value = "0";
    Integer Value = Integer.parseInt(p_Value);
    if (Frequency.equals("W"))
        return (Integer)Value;
    else if (Frequency.equals("F"))
        return (Integer)((Value / 2));
    else if (Frequency.equals("M"))
        return (Integer)((Value * 12) / 52);
    else if (Frequency.equals("Q"))
        return (Integer)((Value * 4) / 52);
    else if (Frequency.equals("Y"))
        return (Integer)(Value / 52);
    else
        return 0;

}
```

It always returns the calue of the variable "Value" even though it matches the different cases. 
for eg. it goes to "return (Integer)((Value * 12) / 52);" but then goes to return 0 and returns "Value". Might be a stupid question but stuck on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int`.and check your `Value` is always 0.

```
 int Value = Integer.parseInt(p_Value); and return type also `int`.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the length of `p_Value` is always 0.  Also, it's bad practice to name variables with a capital first letter.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the return type of method from Integer to double or long or float
because int always return numeric not a fractional part and your calculation is returning `.something` and that is converted into `0` so make sure that use the return type of such calculation method is always double or float etc.

```
private Integer calculateWeeklyValue(String p_Value, String Frequency) {}

                     to 

private double calculateWeeklyValue(String p_Value, String Frequency)
```